# Electron-update not working - Maximum allowed size is 50 MB

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

My Electron application can't update since my last release.

i get this error :

```
Cannot download differentially, fallback to full download: Error: Maximum allowed size is 50 MB
```

Anyone has a solution for this problem ?

My dependencies :

-"electron-builder": "^22.8.0"

-"electron-updater": "^4.3.5"

-"electron": "^9.0.3"

Thank,

thomas

Comment: Same for me did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but I ran into the same problem and solved it by upgrading my electron builder and electron updater versions. Previously they had limit of 50MB for downloading update but now its 500 MB in latest versions through electron auto updater. In case anyone is interested below are versions I am running:

`"electron-updater": "4.3.9",`

`"electron": "13.2.1",`

`"electron-builder": "22.11.7",`